# IE11 JavaScript Syntax Error on class, built with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I can't make Babel convert ES6 class definition to ES5 that would work in IE11. JavaScript compiles just fine, it works fine in modern browsers but it still leaves class definitions in ES6 form which breaks the IE11.

This is my webpack.js:

```
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            options: {
                presets : [
                  [ "@babel/preset-env", {
                     "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                     "targets": {
                        "browsers": [
                           "last 5 versions",
                           "ie >= 10"
                        ]
                     },
                     "debug":true
                  }]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},

entry:
    [path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/js/app.js")],

...
};
```

I have also included babel polyfill to top of my js file

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? How did you solve it? I have the same problem so any help from you will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Change package.json to this:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "vue-cli-service build **--watch**",
    ...
  },
```

2. npm run build

This will solve your problem.
Without `--watch` you got Script error in IE11.

Comment: Can you explain why `--watch` effects the built output?

Answer (score 0):

Babel does not transform classes by itself, you need a plugin for that.

> https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-classes

Step 1:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-classes
```

Step 2: Add this in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-classes"]
}
```